# Java rest s3 put

Tags: java, rest, amazon-s3

Found a nice bit of code. For creating a bucket in s3 environment.
http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2007/11/07/introduction-to-amazon-s3-with-java-and-rest.html.

But I cannot find a way to modify the code for a put object.
This is the info needed as specified by the documentation.

```
    PUT / ObjectName HTTP/1.1 
    Host: BucketName .s3.amazonaws.com 
    Date: date 
    Authorization: signatureValue
```

But I keep receiving error Invalid HTTP method: PUT / filename.txt

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: The difference I can see in your code and in the code available via that link is that you use "/ ObjectName" (with space) and that example uses "/ObjectName" without space.
May this be the reason for an error?

Comment: No, still get the same error. Thanks though.

Comment: Another crazy idea but who knows?.. Try "filename" without an extension (don't really think it should help, but maybe...).
Also I've noticed there is no Content-Length header in your request.

Comment: Nope can't find the file to upload if I remove the extension.